# Compute all terms up to order 4 in the power series expansion at the origin of f(z)=...

Tags: complex-analysis

Q: Compute all terms up to order $4$ in the power series expansion at the origin of $$f(z)=\frac{\sin(3z)}{z^2-4z+3}.$$

How I try to solve this is by:

1) Take a random polynom, $p(x)$: $Ax^4+Bx^3+C^2+Dx+E$ = $p(x)$.

2) it should now apply: $p(x) \cdot(z^2-4z+3) = \sin(3z)$

I calculated with help Taylor series:

$$\sin(3z) = 3z - \frac{(3x)^2}{3!} + O(z^5)$$ which is $$3z-\frac{z^2}{2} + O(z^5)$$

so??

$$p(z) \cdot (z^2-4z+3) =3z-\frac{x^2}{2} + O(z^5) $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow (Ax^4+Bx^3+Cx^2+Dx+E)(z^2-4z+3) = 3z-\frac{x^2}{2} + O(z^5)$$

But it's here where I get lost,

Maybe it's wrong of me to have $p(x)$, maybe  I should use $p(z)$ if yes, we get:

$$(Az^4+Bz^3+Cz^2+Dz+E)(z^2-4z+3) = 3z-\frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^5)$$

So this is (I don't calculate it all since we have Olbe, $O^5$ which is gonna "eat" all the power bigger than $5$, which is gonna be (when we multiply the parenthesis) :

$$(Cz^2+Dz+E)(z^2-4z+3) = 3z-\frac{z^2}{2} + O(z^5)$$

So I guess I just can calculate it now?

$$Cz^4-4Cz^3+3z^2+Dz^3-3Dz^2+3Dz+Ez^2-4Ez+3E=3z-\frac{z^2}{2}$$

What the....

I don't know how I can continue.

Comment: Why did you write $x$ instead of $z$ in the second term for $\sin (3z)$?

Comment: that was just a misstake, but I think you know what I mean :)

Comment: Note:  $z^2-4z+3=(z-1)(z-3)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner okey, but maybe I'm dumb, but it dosen't make me any more smarter =(

Answer (score 1):

Part of your difficulty is that you need the correct series for $\sin3z$. But as @JWTanner pointed out it is easier to use the series for $\frac{1}{1-z}$ and $\frac{1}{3-z}$. Then all you have to do is to multiply the three series together. So you want:

$$\left(3z+\frac{9}{2}z^3\right)\left(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4\right)\left(\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}z+\frac{1}{27}z^2+\frac{1}{81}z^3+\frac{1}{243}z^4\right)+O(z^5)$$

$$=z+\frac{4}{3}z^2-\frac{1}{18}z^3-\frac{14}{27}z^4+O(z^5)$$

Or use long division as suggested by @ClaudeLeibovici (your approach didn't seem to be straight long division). Or use the Taylor series by differentiating to get the first few derivatives at $z=0$.

Comment: so the correct answer is: $z+\frac{4}{3}z^2-\frac{1}{18}z^3-\frac{14}{27}z^4$ (I guess I don't answer Olbe?

Comment: because the answer should look like:

Answer = __z^0 + __z + __z^2 + __z^3 + ___z^4

Answer (score 0):

You could do it that way but you will need much more terms for the rhs. Using your notation, you need at least $z^6$ in the expansion
$$(Az^4+Bz^3+Cz^2+Dz+E)(z^2-4z+3)=3 z-\frac{9 z^3}{2}+\frac{81 z^5}{40}-\frac{243 z^7}{560}+O\left(z^{9}\right)$$

Easier would be
$$f(z)=\frac{\sin(3z)}{z^2-4z+3}=\frac{3 z-\frac{9 }{2}z^3+\frac{81 }{40}z^5-\frac{243 }{560}z^7+O\left(z^9\right)}{z^2-4z+3}$$ and use long division.

Comment: http://www.bilddump.se/bilder/20191002150835-83.249.31.213.jpeg here is my calculations. But.. it seems reeeeally screwed!